# How to fix "Class not found" Error when it is in the filesystem

Tags: groups, mailing, subscribe

When a Civi Contact wants to **resubscribe to a Mailing List** the contact was previously subscribed to, I get the following error:

**Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Class '*CRM_Mailing_Event_BAO_Resubscribe*' not found in ./civicrm/CRM/Mailing/Page/Common.php:80

The Class "***CRM_Mailing_Event_BAO_Resubscribe***" is contained in a php file, *MailingEventResubscribe.php*, which is in the filesystem within the directory ./**civicrm/CRM/Mailing/Event/BAO** with the right permissions *644*.

This class is invoked from ./**civicrm/CRM/Mailing/Page**/Common.php file.

I would appreciate any help to fix that error so that this class can be found.

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: WordPress 5.9.5 CiviCRM 5.57.0 PHP 7.4 MySQL 5.7.36

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved by renaming the class in "*MailingEventResubscribe.php*" to **CRM_Mailing_Event_BAO_MailingEventResubscribe**, and invoking this new renamed class in the "*Common.php*" file.